# How to repair a corrupted MPTT tree (nested set) in the database using SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, nested-sets, mptt

I have an MPTT tree of over 100,000 records stored in MySQL using `lft`, `rght` and `parent_id` columns. Now the left/right values became corrupted, while the parent ids are still intact. It would require tons of queries to repair it in the application layer. Is there a good way to put the burden on the database and have it recalculate the left/right values using only SQL?

---

Just to clarify, I need to recalculate the numeric lft/rght values of a [nested set](https://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), not the ids of neighboring records.

[image: The Nested Set]
<sub>(source: [mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data-4.png))</sub>

Comment: Is the list from left to right for a given parent_id ordered in any way?

Comment: @Lieven Not particularly. To generalize the answer it would be a great if the order could be preserved, but it's absolutely not necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using SQL Server, following script seems to be working for me.

### Output testscript

```
category_id name                 parent      lft         rgt         lftcalc     rgtcalc
----------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           ELECTRONICS          NULL        1           20          1           20
2           TELEVISIONS          1           2           9           2           9
3           TUBE                 2           3           4           3           4
4           LCD                  2           5           6           5           6
5           PLASMA               2           7           8           7           8
6           PORTABLE ELECTRONICS 1           10          19          10          19
7           MP3 PLAYERS          6           11          14          11          14
8           FLASH                7           12          13          12          13
9           CD PLAYERS           6           15          16          15          16
10          2 WAY RADIOS         6           17          18          17          18
```

### Script

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

DECLARE @nested_category TABLE (
 category_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 parent INT,
 lft INT,
 rgt INT
);

DECLARE @current_Category_ID INTEGER
DECLARE @current_parent INTEGER
DECLARE @SafeGuard INTEGER
DECLARE @myLeft INTEGER
SET @SafeGuard = 100

INSERT INTO @nested_category 
SELECT           1,'ELECTRONICS',NULL,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'TELEVISIONS',1,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'TUBE',2,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'LCD',2,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'PLASMA',2,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 6,'PORTABLE ELECTRONICS',1,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 7,'MP3 PLAYERS',6,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 8,'FLASH',7,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 9,'CD PLAYERS',6,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 10,'2 WAY RADIOS',6,NULL,NULL

/* Initialize */
UPDATE  @nested_category 
SET     lft = 1
        , rgt = 2
WHERE   parent IS NULL

UPDATE  @nested_category 
SET     lft = NULL
        , rgt = NULL
WHERE   parent IS NOT NULL

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @nested_category WHERE lft IS NULL) AND @SafeGuard > 0
BEGIN
  SELECT  @current_Category_ID = MAX(nc.category_id)
  FROM    @nested_category nc
          INNER JOIN @nested_category nc2 ON nc2.category_id = nc.parent
  WHERE   nc.lft IS NULL
          AND nc2.lft IS NOT NULL

  SELECT  @current_parent = parent
  FROM    @nested_category
  WHERE   category_id = @current_category_id

  SELECT  @myLeft = lft
  FROM    @nested_category
  WHERE   category_id = @current_parent

  UPDATE @nested_category SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myLeft;
  UPDATE @nested_category SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myLeft;
  UPDATE @nested_category SET lft = @myLeft + 1, rgt = @myLeft + 2 WHERE category_id = @current_category_id

  SET @SafeGuard = @SafeGuard - 1
END

SELECT * FROM @nested_category ORDER BY category_id

SELECT  COUNT(node.name), node.name, MIN(node.lft)
FROM    @nested_category AS node,
        @nested_category AS parent
WHERE   node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY 
        node.name
ORDER BY
        3, 1
```

### Testscript ##

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

DECLARE @nested_category TABLE (
 category_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 parent INT,
 lft INT,
 rgt INT, 
 lftcalc INT,
 rgtcalc INT
);

INSERT INTO @nested_category 
SELECT           1,'ELECTRONICS',NULL,1,20,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'TELEVISIONS',1,2,9,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'TUBE',2,3,4,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'LCD',2,5,6,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'PLASMA',2,7,8,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 6,'PORTABLE ELECTRONICS',1,10,19,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 7,'MP3 PLAYERS',6,11,14,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 8,'FLASH',7,12,13,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 9,'CD PLAYERS',6,15,16,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 10,'2 WAY RADIOS',6,17,18,NULL,NULL

/* Initialize */
UPDATE  @nested_category 
SET     lftcalc = 1
        , rgtcalc = 2
WHERE   parent IS NULL

DECLARE @current_Category_ID INTEGER
DECLARE @current_parent INTEGER
DECLARE @SafeGuard INTEGER
DECLARE @myRight INTEGER
DECLARE @myLeft INTEGER
SET @SafeGuard = 100
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @nested_category WHERE lftcalc IS NULL) AND @SafeGuard > 0
BEGIN
  SELECT  @current_Category_ID = MAX(nc.category_id)
  FROM    @nested_category nc
          INNER JOIN @nested_category nc2 ON nc2.category_id = nc.parent
  WHERE   nc.lftcalc IS NULL
          AND nc2.lftcalc IS NOT NULL

  SELECT  @current_parent = parent
  FROM    @nested_category
  WHERE   category_id = @current_category_id

  SELECT  @myLeft = lftcalc
  FROM    @nested_category
  WHERE   category_id = @current_parent

  UPDATE @nested_category SET rgtcalc = rgtcalc + 2 WHERE rgtcalc > @myLeft;
  UPDATE @nested_category SET lftcalc = lftcalc + 2 WHERE lftcalc > @myLeft;
  UPDATE @nested_category SET lftcalc = @myLeft + 1, rgtcalc = @myLeft + 2 WHERE category_id = @current_category_id

  SELECT * FROM @nested_category WHERE category_id = @current_parent
  SELECT * FROM @nested_category ORDER BY category_id
  SET @SafeGuard = @SafeGuard - 1
END

SELECT * FROM @nested_category ORDER BY category_id

SELECT  COUNT(node.name), node.name, MIN(node.lft)
FROM    @nested_category AS node,
        @nested_category AS parent
WHERE   node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY 
        node.name
ORDER BY
        3, 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but MySQL doesn't seem to support `UPDATE FROM`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html

Comment: @deceze, I have altered the script how it might work with MySQL.

Comment: Just to make sure, the same question I had for Brian: Does this set the *neighboring ids* or *calculate the lft/rght values of a nested set*?

Comment: @deceze, it sets the neighboring ids, not what you want. I'll have a think too.

Comment: @deceze: the new scripts works, using SQL Server, with the data presented in your link. I believe it should be relatively easy to convert it to MySQL.

Comment: @deceze, the script starts with the assumption that lft and rgt are NULL. I've edited the script to reflect this.

Comment: I'm in the middle of translating the script to MySQL and playing around with it. I found one major problem: The script expects only one root node (parent_id = NULL), but I have several. Trying to work around this...

Comment: Thanks again, your answer definitely brought me on the right track. The script is still running, but it seems to be working, and a lot more efficiently so than throwing a ton a queries at the database from the application layer. :)

Comment: @deceze - Curious about your workaround but mine would be to create a dummy root, have all your current roots link to that, run the script and remove the dummy root (and links) afterwards.

Comment: Well, see my adapted version below… :)

Comment: Okay, it ran all throughout the weekend and has about 4000 records left to process now. I think it's slowing down as it goes on since it has to push more and more values to the right each time. If you have any ideas for optimizations, I'm all ear. :)

Comment: I would assume adding an index to lft and rgt might help. It would require additional housekeeping for the indexes but the indexex should get used when selecting records to be updated. All in all, I would suspect the runtime curve starting higher but staying (more) flat than without indexes.

Comment: There actually are indexes on all affected columns, which is actually part of why it's so slow. I opened [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648970/how-to-optimize-a-col-col-1-update-query-that-runs-on-100-000-records) in the meantime about optimizing the queries. Using a temporary MEMORY table seems like the only real way to get it from a seconds-per-record to a records-per-second rate. :)

Comment: Thanks for the link to you new question. I would have missed it otherwise. Interesting reads so far.

Answer (score 24):

Here's what I have adapted from @Lieven's answer, incorporating feedback from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648970/how-to-optimize-a-col-col-1-update-query-that-runs-on-100-000-records) for better performance:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS tree_recover;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE tree_recover ()
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

    DECLARE currentId, currentParentId  CHAR(36);
    DECLARE currentLeft                 INT;
    DECLARE startId                     INT DEFAULT 1;

    # Determines the max size for MEMORY tables.
    SET max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 512;

    START TRANSACTION;

    # Temporary MEMORY table to do all the heavy lifting in,
    # otherwise performance is simply abysmal.
    CREATE TABLE `tmp_tree` (
        `id`        char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `parent_id` char(36)          DEFAULT NULL,
        `lft`       int(11)  unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
        `rght`      int(11)  unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY      (`id`),
        INDEX USING HASH (`parent_id`),
        INDEX USING HASH (`lft`),
        INDEX USING HASH (`rght`)
    ) ENGINE = MEMORY
    SELECT `id`,
           `parent_id`,
           `lft`,
           `rght`
    FROM   `tree`;

    # Leveling the playing field.
    UPDATE  `tmp_tree`
    SET     `lft`  = NULL,
            `rght` = NULL;

    # Establishing starting numbers for all root elements.
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `tmp_tree` WHERE `parent_id` IS NULL AND `lft` IS NULL AND `rght` IS NULL LIMIT 1) DO

        UPDATE `tmp_tree`
        SET    `lft`  = startId,
               `rght` = startId + 1
        WHERE  `parent_id` IS NULL
          AND  `lft`       IS NULL
          AND  `rght`      IS NULL
        LIMIT  1;

        SET startId = startId + 2;

    END WHILE;

    # Switching the indexes for the lft/rght columns to B-Trees to speed up the next section, which uses range queries.
    DROP INDEX `lft`  ON `tmp_tree`;
    DROP INDEX `rght` ON `tmp_tree`;
    CREATE INDEX `lft`  USING BTREE ON `tmp_tree` (`lft`);
    CREATE INDEX `rght` USING BTREE ON `tmp_tree` (`rght`);

    # Numbering all child elements
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `tmp_tree` WHERE `lft` IS NULL LIMIT 1) DO

        # Picking an unprocessed element which has a processed parent.
        SELECT     `tmp_tree`.`id`
          INTO     currentId
        FROM       `tmp_tree`
        INNER JOIN `tmp_tree` AS `parents`
                ON `tmp_tree`.`parent_id` = `parents`.`id`
        WHERE      `tmp_tree`.`lft` IS NULL
          AND      `parents`.`lft`  IS NOT NULL
        LIMIT      1;

        # Finding the element's parent.
        SELECT  `parent_id`
          INTO  currentParentId
        FROM    `tmp_tree`
        WHERE   `id` = currentId;

        # Finding the parent's lft value.
        SELECT  `lft`
          INTO  currentLeft
        FROM    `tmp_tree`
        WHERE   `id` = currentParentId;

        # Shifting all elements to the right of the current element 2 to the right.
        UPDATE `tmp_tree`
        SET    `rght` = `rght` + 2
        WHERE  `rght` > currentLeft;

        UPDATE `tmp_tree`
        SET    `lft` = `lft` + 2
        WHERE  `lft` > currentLeft;

        # Setting lft and rght values for current element.
        UPDATE `tmp_tree`
        SET    `lft`  = currentLeft + 1,
               `rght` = currentLeft + 2
        WHERE  `id`   = currentId;

    END WHILE;

    # Writing calculated values back to physical table.
    UPDATE `tree`, `tmp_tree`
    SET    `tree`.`lft`  = `tmp_tree`.`lft`,
           `tree`.`rght` = `tmp_tree`.`rght`
    WHERE  `tree`.`id`   = `tmp_tree`.`id`;

    COMMIT;

    DROP TABLE `tmp_tree`;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

<strike>Worked well with some test data, but it's still running on my 100,000 records tree, so I can't give any final judgement yet.</strike> The naïve script working directly on the physical table has abysmal performance, running for at least hours, more likely days. Switching to a temporary MEMORY table brought this time down to about an hour, choosing the right indexes cut it down to 10 mins.

Comment: To those who will use this script after me: don't forget to adjust it to your database! I spent a day in endless loop before realizing that the root's parent_id is Joomla nested-set tables is zero, not NULL. Thanks anyway for the script, deceze, it finishes instantly with my few hundred rows per table now when I use it correctly! My mistake at least gave me time to make some progress on another, less computation-heavy project :-)

Comment: Wow, this was a great help. My table contained ~1,500,000 records! Thanks deceze and @Pavel-V for the tip about zero parent id for root.

Answer (score 5):

You are rescue me!!! I use mixed tree model, so when the day is coming, my tree (30000+) was corrupted. I learn from both of your tech, but is not recovery, just fully rebuild with lost all of sorting and reverse tree...
I think, need to keep in mind older cat_left.... Just for possible integrity. So, it maybe looks like...

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS tree_recover;

DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE tree_recover ()
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

    DECLARE currentId, currentParentId  CHAR(36);
    DECLARE currentLeft                 INT;
    DECLARE startId                     INT DEFAULT 1;

    # Determines the max size for MEMORY tables.
    SET max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 512;

    START TRANSACTION;

    # Temporary MEMORY table to do all the heavy lifting in,
    # otherwise performance is simply abysmal.
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tmp_cat`;
    CREATE TABLE `tmp_cat` (
        `cat_id`        char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `cat_parent` char(36)          DEFAULT NULL,
        `cat_left`       int(11)  unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
        `cat_right`      int(11)  unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
        `cat_left_old`   int(11)  unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY      (`cat_id`),
        INDEX USING HASH (`cat_parent`),
        INDEX USING HASH (`cat_left`),
        INDEX USING HASH (`cat_right`),
    INDEX USING HASH (`cat_left_old`)
    ) ENGINE = MEMORY
    SELECT `cat_id`,
           `cat_parent`,
           `cat_left`,
           `cat_right`,
       `cat_left` as cat_left_old
    FROM   `catalog`;

    # Leveling the playing field.
    UPDATE  `tmp_cat`
    SET     `cat_left`  = NULL,
            `cat_right` = NULL;

    # Establishing starting numbers for all root elements.
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `tmp_cat` WHERE `cat_parent` IS NULL AND `cat_left` IS NULL AND `cat_right` IS NULL ORDER BY cat_left_old LIMIT 1) DO

        UPDATE `tmp_cat`
        SET    `cat_left`  = startId,
               `cat_right` = startId + 1
        WHERE  `cat_parent` IS NULL
          AND  `cat_left`       IS NULL
          AND  `cat_right`      IS NULL
        LIMIT  1;

        SET startId = startId + 2;

    END WHILE;

    # Switching the indexes for the cat_left/rght columns to B-Trees to speed up the next section, which uses range queries.
    DROP INDEX `cat_left`  ON `tmp_cat`;
    DROP INDEX `cat_right` ON `tmp_cat`;
    DROP INDEX `cat_left_old` ON `tmp_cat`;

    CREATE INDEX `cat_left`  USING BTREE ON `tmp_cat` (`cat_left`);
    CREATE INDEX `cat_right` USING BTREE ON `tmp_cat` (`cat_right`);
    CREATE INDEX `cat_left_old` USING BTREE ON `tmp_cat` (`cat_left_old`);

    # Numbering all child elements
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `tmp_cat` WHERE `cat_left` IS NULL ORDER BY cat_left_old LIMIT 1) DO

        # Picking an unprocessed element which has a processed parent.
        SELECT     `tmp_cat`.`cat_id`
          INTO     currentId
        FROM       `tmp_cat`
        INNER JOIN `tmp_cat` AS `parents`
                ON `tmp_cat`.`cat_parent` = `parents`.`cat_id`
        WHERE      `tmp_cat`.`cat_left` IS NULL
          AND      `parents`.`cat_left`  IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY `tmp_cat`.cat_left_old DESC
        LIMIT      1;

        # Finding the element's parent.
        SELECT  `cat_parent`
          INTO  currentParentId
        FROM    `tmp_cat`
        WHERE   `cat_id` = currentId;

        # Finding the parent's cat_left value.
        SELECT  `cat_left`
          INTO  currentLeft
        FROM    `tmp_cat`
        WHERE   `cat_id` = currentParentId;

        # Shifting all elements to the right of the current element 2 to the right.
        UPDATE `tmp_cat`
        SET    `cat_right` = `cat_right` + 2
        WHERE  `cat_right` > currentLeft;

        UPDATE `tmp_cat`
        SET    `cat_left` = `cat_left` + 2
        WHERE  `cat_left` > currentLeft;

        # Setting cat_left and rght values for current element.
        UPDATE `tmp_cat`
        SET    `cat_left`  = currentLeft + 1,
               `cat_right` = currentLeft + 2
        WHERE  `cat_id`   = currentId;

    END WHILE;

    # Writing calculated values back to physical table.
    UPDATE `catalog`, `tmp_cat`
    SET    `catalog`.`cat_left`  = `tmp_cat`.`cat_left`,
           `catalog`.`cat_right` = `tmp_cat`.`cat_right`
    WHERE  `catalog`.`cat_id`   = `tmp_cat`.`cat_id`;

    COMMIT;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tmp_cat`;

END|
```

Comment: Please rephrase some of your sentence since they are hard to understand. Personally I have a hard time understanding what you mean!

Answer (score 1):

In all solutions provided, I was getting a problem where MySQL would prompt that it would be `Running query` for hours but nothing would happen.

I then realized that if I set the lft and rght values to 1 and 2 in the first record of the tmp_tree table (the one with `parent_id = 0`), everything worked fine. Maybe the procedure needs updating to do this automatically.