# Akeneo categories bug, I do not hope for an answer, I hope for a little clearance

Tags: categories, akeneo, pim

So I have this problem, I have automated product import to akeneo from supplier, while trying to upgrade performance of the code i broke something, now I have problems with child categories, Cannot access them from products some suppliers go good, some bugged. Whole week now Im trying to connect dont swhat happened now I went across this category table [image]

Im not sure what the columns `lft` `rgt` means it is not first time i see them but never actualy cleared what do they do. Just tought maybe this could help me to debug stuff

Answer (score 0):

This is a nested set model, it's a technique for representing nested sets (also known as trees or hierarchies) in relational databases.

You can find more informations about this model [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)

Answer (score 0):

For people that has the exact same problem where the nested sets are complete off for some reason.

> before doing anything of this please backup your database!

With some help from an another post: [How to repair a corrupted MPTT tree (nested set) in the database using SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623645/how-to-repair-a-corrupted-mptt-tree-nested-set-in-the-database-using-sql)

changed the sql to work with Akeneo categories:

add this procedure to your database:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS tree_recover;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE tree_recover ()
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

    DECLARE currentId, currentParentId  CHAR(36);
    DECLARE currentLeft                 INT;
    DECLARE startId                     INT DEFAULT 1;

    # Determines the max size for MEMORY tables.
    SET max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 512;

    START TRANSACTION;

    # Temporary MEMORY table to do all the heavy lifting in,
    # otherwise performance is simply abysmal.
    CREATE TABLE `tmp_tree` (
        `id`        int(36) NOT NULL,
        `parent_id` int(36),
        `lft`       int(11) unsigned,
        `rgt`      int(11)  unsigned,
        PRIMARY KEY      (`id`),
        INDEX USING HASH (`parent_id`),
        INDEX USING HASH (`lft`),
        INDEX USING HASH (`rgt`)
    ) ENGINE = MEMORY
    SELECT `id`,
           `parent_id`,
           `lft`,
           `rgt`
    FROM   `pim_catalog_category`;

# Leveling the playing field.
UPDATE  `tmp_tree`
SET     `lft`  = 0,
        `rgt` = 0;
# Establishing starting numbers for all root elements.
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `tmp_tree` WHERE `parent_id` IS NULL AND `lft` = 0 AND `rgt` = 0 LIMIT 1) DO


        UPDATE `tmp_tree`
        SET    `lft`  = startId,
               `rgt` = startId + 1
        WHERE  `parent_id` IS NULL
          AND  `lft`       = 0
          AND  `rgt`      = 0
        LIMIT  1;

        SET startId = startId + 2;

    END WHILE;

    # Switching the indexes for the lft/rgt columns to B-Trees to speed up the next section, which uses range queries.
    DROP INDEX `lft`  ON `tmp_tree`;
    DROP INDEX `rgt` ON `tmp_tree`;
    CREATE INDEX `lft`  USING BTREE ON `tmp_tree` (`lft`);
    CREATE INDEX `rgt` USING BTREE ON `tmp_tree` (`rgt`);

    # Numbering all child elements
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `tmp_tree` WHERE `lft` = 0 LIMIT 1) DO

        # Picking an unprocessed element which has a processed parent.
        SELECT     `tmp_tree`.`id`
          INTO     currentId
        FROM       `tmp_tree`
        INNER JOIN `tmp_tree` AS `parents`
                ON `tmp_tree`.`parent_id` = `parents`.`id`
        WHERE      `tmp_tree`.`lft` = 0
          AND      `parents`.`lft`  <> 0
        LIMIT      1;

        # Finding the element's parent.
        SELECT  `parent_id`
          INTO  currentParentId
        FROM    `tmp_tree`
        WHERE   `id` = currentId;

        # Finding the parent's lft value.
        SELECT  `lft`
          INTO  currentLeft
        FROM    `tmp_tree`
        WHERE   `id` = currentParentId;

        # Shifting all elements to the right of the current element 2 to the right.
        UPDATE `tmp_tree`
        SET    `rgt` = `rgt` + 2
        WHERE  `rgt` > currentLeft;

        UPDATE `tmp_tree`
        SET    `lft` = `lft` + 2
        WHERE  `lft` > currentLeft;

        # Setting lft and rgt values for current element.
        UPDATE `tmp_tree`
        SET    `lft`  = currentLeft + 1,
               `rgt` = currentLeft + 2
        WHERE  `id`   = currentId;

    END WHILE;

    # Writing calculated values back to physical table.
    UPDATE `pim_catalog_category`, `tmp_tree`
    SET    `pim_catalog_category`.`lft`  = `tmp_tree`.`lft`,
           `pim_catalog_category`.`rgt` = `tmp_tree`.`rgt`
    WHERE  `pim_catalog_category`.`id`   = `tmp_tree`.`id`;

    COMMIT;

    DROP TABLE `tmp_tree`;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

And call it with:

```
CALL tree_recover;
```

on your Akeneo Database

This command can take a couple minutes to days depending how many categories you have

BE AWARE: By executing this command the new lft and rgt calculated values are committed immediately after the process is done.